# Cosa significa "menù a panino"?

Tags: word-meaning

Ovviamente è un termine informatico, tipo "menù a tendina", ma "menù a panino" l'ho sentito oggi per la prima volta.

Comment: "Hamburger" è il nome colloquiale che si dà all'icona con tre barre orizzontali per che si utilizza per aprire il menu (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button), menu a panino potrebbe derivare da lì

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Suona verosimile. Non conoscevo questa espressione, ma cercandola con Google Images si trovano varie icone del tipo che dici. Vuoi scrivere una risposta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Hamburger" è il nome colloquiale che si dà all'icona con tre barre orizzontali che si utilizza per aprire il menu ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button)); l'espressione "menu a panino" a mio parere deriva da questa espressione ed indica un menu che appare al click sull'icona.